# Compile for windows on linux using MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, windows, linux, executable, monodevelop

I want to know, because I can't find anything on google, If I use MonoDevelop to compile an application on Linux, can I send the generated executable to a Windows computer and expect it to run? `file` outputs this:

```
PE32 executable for MS Windows (console) Intel 80386 32-bit Mono/.Net assembly
```

so I would expect it to run on Windows out-of-the box. But I sent it to a friend for testing, and it said 'this is not a valid win32 application'. So, what do I need to do? It is just a basic hello world console application in C#.

Comment: Did he have the right version of .NET installed?

Comment: @kichik
That very well may be the problem...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to have the exact version of Mono installed on the target machine or a matching version of .NET Framework (i.e. if you compiled against Mono 2.10.x, you'll most probably need .NET 4.0). Otherwise you'll get that exact error message.

Comment: Would a later version of .NET work? Or does it have to be exact?

Comment: cool. Thanks! So if I understand correctly, a .NET(or mono) application is basically cross-platform, meaning compile once run anywhere, considering that windows has .NET, and other platforms have mono?

Comment: yes that is correct (but you'll still have to do some testing just to make sure that your app works as expected across all platforms).