# How can I cross-compile a C# project for Windows on Linux?

Tags: c#, linux, msbuild, mono, cross-compiling

Is it possible to compile C# code into binary **for Windows** using `mono` or `msbuild` (or some other solution I don't know about) **on Linux**?

These C# projects usually consist of the following files:

- `.cs`
- `.csproj`
- `.config`
- `.manifest`

Example app configuration:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
      <supportedRuntime version="v4.0.30319" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" />
      <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
    </startup>
</configuration>
```

Example `.csproj` (snippet):

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props')" />
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetZone>Internet</TargetZone>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Deployment" />
    <Reference Include="System.Web" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Client.3.5">
        <Visible>False</Visible>
        <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 Client Profile</ProductName>
        <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
    <BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">
        <Visible>False</Visible>
        <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
        <Install>false</Install>
    </BootstrapperPackage>
</ItemGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
```

**Disclaimer:** I really don't know a lot about Windows. If this is *Simply Not Possible™*, I can use a Windows VM as a last resort.

Comment: This is your answer, i think:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812304/compile-for-windows-on-linux-using-monodevelop

Comment: .net core might also be a option see here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/linux-prerequisites?tabs=netcore2x

Comment: FYI - Targeting either .NET Core (for executables) or .NET Standard (for non-executable class libraries) is the most modern way to do it depending on what type of project it is (which you haven't mentioned). [Build a C# Hello World application with .NET Core in Visual Studio 2017](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio).

Comment: Hard to say what you need to do for your project to be runnable on Windows. More of my C# projects *(compiled on Windows for Windows)* works without any problem on Linux (Mono). I also use a project, that was originally created and compiled in Linux, but work on Windows. *(In both cases the same binary files without any change works on Windows and Linux.)* But there are some functions, that are not supported in Mono. The reverse can also be true. There can be functions, that can not be used on Windows .NET, but you can still probably run them using Mono for Windows. You need to make a test.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I guess they are dotNET applications. I've included a config from one of the projects if it helps.

Comment: @Redsandro - All that tells me is that it is .NET Framework and not .NET Standard/.NET Core. What we need to see are the contents of the `.csproj` file to make that determination.

Comment: @NightOwl888 I've added a snippet

Comment: Mono is not .NET Framework. So if you intend to run your app with Mono on Windows, it should work automatically. There can be issues if you run it on .NET Framework. At a time like this, please simply use .NET Core, which you can publish your app as Windows binaries on Linux (yes, it supports cross compilation).

Answer (score 0):

On linux you should be able to run your assembly just with the mono command.
mono app.exe. No cross compiling needed. (ah the benefits of click once run anywhere)

However if you mean AOT compiled or mkbundle it be easier just to use linux machine.

unless you have dependency in the windows os in which alternatives will need to be found or include a config file.